# Clear store and load search result in grid

Tags: javascript, search, extjs, grid, extjs5

When I load my app, the first component is a grid (with pagingbar).

The grid store has the config autload: true

The app has a second component, a form, used to search, and the result is loaded into the grid.

When I click the search button, if the grid is, for example, on page 2 and the search string exist only on the first page, does not return any results.

The solution that I have used is to go to the first page, remove all records (loaded with autoload: true) and then load the search result.

```
store.loadPage(1) ; 
store.removeAll();
store.proxy.extraParams = {...};
store.load({
  …
});
```

The problem is that solution requires making two consecutive loads and briefly grid displays the starting records (autoload), remove them and then displays the search result.

My target is to clear the grid (store) to load the search result correctly.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just:

```
store.proxy.extraParams = {...};
store.loadPage(1, {...});
```

unless you use `clearOnPageLoad: false`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing two loads, pass the params in the loadPage function of the store:

```
store.loadPage(1,{
    params: your_params, //store.proxy.extraParams = {...};
    callback: function(records,operation,success){
        //your code
    }
});
```

Comment: If you add search param via `loadPage()` options it will affect only this single request, I guess we have to add search param to store `extraParams` as it should affect all subsequent requests before search fiels is cleared or something like it.

Comment: But if we clean all the search fields, the expected result should be all the records (because there is no filter) and not the records filtered by the extraParams or ¿Did i misunderstood your comment >.<?

Comment: If we clear search field we have to remove search param from store `extraParams`, but if we pass seach param to `loadPage()` options and, for example, filtered data set contains many pages on `nextPage()` we will load unfiltered data set.

Comment: Thanks qmat for your sugestion

Comment: Thank sergey I am right now trying to implement your suggestions and I am better reflect on this issue in accordance with your directions ...